# Is it possible to enable compression on QuickBooks SDK Web Connector?

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml

I am transferring a rather large amount of data using the QuickBooks Web Connector to a remote server, and I'm pretty sure that the internet bandwidth is the main bottleneck for most of the transfer. Is there a way to configure the Web Connector to enable compression when it transfers data?

Answer (score 0):

According to intuit, quickbooks web connector does not support compression of any kind.